# Swift: вращение `imageView`

Tags: ios, swift

Есть этот код для того чтобы вращать `imageView` вокруг своей оси (вертикальная линия проведенная по центру от верхнего края к нижнему):

```
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000.0
self.imageRevealed1.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Но мне нужно вращать `imageView` вокруг ее левой грани. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вращения необходимо сместить `anchorPoint` и использовать `transform.m34` при вращении, это даст эффект, что одна строна при вращении к нам "ближе".

Пример кода:

```
imageToRotate.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -0.001
imageToRotate.layer.transform = transform
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
    self.imageToRotate.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi, 0, 1, 0)
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только у меня `imageView` в `storyboard` с ограничениями. А при `anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)`  `imageView` смещается с нужной позиции и анимация начинается правее.